# MethodError in Inner Constructor with Vector Input

Tags: vector, struct, constructor, linked-list, julia

I'm trying to implement a SparsePolynomial type that stores the terms as items in a linked list (from DataStructures.jl) with a dictionary pointing to items in the linked list. This struct takes input as a vector of `Term`s, another struct I've created. This will work for when I put in a vector of non-zero `Term`s. When I try to use an inner constructor to create the zero polynomial using `SparsePolynomial()` as below, it returns an error: `MethodError: Cannot convert an object of type Vector{Term} to an object of type MutableLinkedList{Term}`. I have already defined a method for `zero(Term)`, which works otherwise.

```
struct PolynomialSparse

  terms:: MutableLinkedList{Term} 
  dict:: Dict{Int, DataStructures.ListNode{Term}} 

  #Inner constructor of the 0 polynomial
  PolynomialSparse() = new([zero(Term)])
  
  #Inner constructor of polynomial based on arbitrary list of terms
  function PolynomialSparse(terms::Vector{Term})
      #Filter the vector so that there is not more than a single zero term
      terms = sort(filter((t)->!iszero(t), terms))
      if isempty(terms)
          terms = [zero(Term)]
      end
      # initialise empty linked list and dictionary
      lst = MutableLinkedList{Term}()
      dict = Dict{Int, DataStructures.ListNode{Term}}()
      # create list and dictionary out of the vector of terms
      for t in terms
          insert_sorted!(lst, dict, t.degree, t)
      end

      return new(lst, dict)
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is `insert_sorted!` from? And could you please post the Stacktrace of the error too?

Comment: have you tried `PolynomialSparse() = PolynomialSparse([zero(Term)])` ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe my issue was that I was trying to create a `PolynomialSparse` with the field of a vector of the zero term - the source of my confusion was that the inner constructor of the polynomial is a function that takes a vector of terms as an input, but the struct itself has the fields of 1. a mutable linked list and 2. a dictionary, so it wouldn't work. The solution I found that has worked so far is replacing the inner constructor of the zero polynomial with this:

```
PolynomialSparse() = new(MutableLinkedList{Term}(zero(Term)), Dict{Int, DataStructures.ListNode{Term}}(0=>DataStructures.ListNode{Term}(zero(Term))))
```